# Uniform distribution - proportion of times this person has to wait

Tags: probability, distributions

I'm going over the teacher's solutions for a past homework assignment and I'm having trouble understanding the solution for one of the questions. I don't understand what the values plugged into each equation are supposed to represent?

Is there a specific formula the teacher was following? I can't seem to figure it out and why he did what he did. Like where did the reciprocal of 30 come from?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(a) The relevant uniform distribution is $X = \mathsf{Unif}(0, 30).$
You seek $P(X \ge 10).$ In the figure below, you want the area under
the density curve (actually *line* in this case) to the right of the vertical dotted line at $x = 10.$

[image]

The desired area is that of a rectangle with base $20$ and height $1/30,$ so
$P(X \ge 10) = 2/3.$

(b) In this case you seek $P(5 \le X \le 15).$ This time you want the area
under the density between the two vertical dotted lines.
So $P(5 \le X \le 15) = 10(1/30) = 1/3.$

[image]